# Newton's Third Law and Constant Velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, collision

How can an object that's not accelerating cause another stationary object to move in a collision? This website: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/Class/momentum/U4l2a.cfm, says that a "rightward **moving**" 7-ball experiences a leftward force when it hits an 8-ball, and the 8-ball experiences a rightward force, but where is this force coming from when the ball was moving with a constant velocity before the collision?

How does Newton's third law explain any collisions that involve a constant velocity?

EDIT: Does it slow down because of the normal force? And then, is there a normal force action-reaction pair? And, if so, how do you calculate the magnitude of the normal force?

Comment: Will the velocities be constant upon impact?

Comment: Yes, they will be.

Comment: So the 7-ball passes through the 8-ball unimpeded?

Comment: The force originates from the 2nd law not the 3rd.

Comment: @Kyle That's what I concluded, but that makes no sense

Comment: @ja72 How does the force originate from the 2nd law? The 2nd law only says that objects will maintain their state of motion. How does maintaining a state of motion create a collision?

Comment: @glaba, that is the 1st law. The [2nd law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_second_law) states the total force equals the rate of change of linear momentum.

Comment: @glaba: It makes no sense because the balls do **not** maintain a constant velocity upon impact. The 7-ball will either **slow down** or **reverse direction** while the 8-ball **begins** to move.

Comment: Does it slow down because of the normal force? And then, is there a normal force action-reaction pair? And, if so, how do you calculate the magnitude of the normal force?

Comment: @ja72 Wow, sorry. My bad. I'm obviously just starting at this, and clearly, it's not in my head yet.

Comment: No problem. I suggest you edit your original question to reflect the question you just stated now. Then you will get an answer.

Comment: @glaba: It slows down because the 7-ball imparted some of its momentum ($p=m\cdot v$) to the 8-ball. Any change in momentum is a change in force: $F=\Delta p/\Delta t$.

Comment: The question just got answered, so let me just make sure that I understand this correctly: Newton's third law doesn't cause the change in speed; conservation of momentum does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the normal force applied over an tiny amount of time changes the speed (momentum) of the objects. The exact magnitude of the force depends on the time it takes for the impact to happen.

A force $F$ applied for a time period $\Delta t$ has [impulse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_%28physics%29) of $ J = F \Delta t $. The impulse is equal to the change of linear momentum in an opposing fashion (3rd law)

$$ \begin{aligned}  
m_1 \Delta v_1 & = J \\
m_2 \Delta v_2 & = -J
\end{aligned} $$

The impact is characterized by a certain [coefficient of restitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution) $\epsilon$ definiting the final relative velocities $v_1^F$ and $v_2^F$ in terms of the initial velocities $v_1^I$ and $v_2^I$ as

$$ \begin{aligned} 
(v_2^F-v_1^F) & = -\epsilon (v_2^I-v_1^I) \\
(v_2^I + \Delta v_2-v_1^I - \Delta v_1) & = -\epsilon (v_2^I-v_1^I) \\
( \Delta v_2 - \Delta v_1) & = -(\epsilon+1) (v_2^I-v_1^I) \\
\frac{-J}{m_2} - \frac{J}{m_1} & = -(\epsilon+1) (v_2^I-v_1^I)
\end{aligned}$$

$$ J = \frac{(1+\epsilon) v_{rel} } { \frac{1}{m_2} + \frac{1}{m_1} } $$

where $v_{rel}  = v_2^I-v_1^I$ is the impact relative velocity. Once $J$ is known, $\Delta v_1$ and $\Delta v_2$ are calculated, as well as the force $F = \frac{J}{\Delta t}$.

Comment: I never knew about the coefficient of restitution! Which brings up a good question: why don't many beginner physics resources have any information about it? But, regardless, thank you for the answer; you've solved a problem about momentum and Newton's Third Law that's been bugging me for a long time.

Comment: Well to my experience most physics books that talk about collisions and momentum _do_ have the COR.